# What's the most elegant/right way to stop a spark job running on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm new to apache spark and I'm trying to run a spark job using spark-submit on my Kubernetes cluster. I was wondering if there's a right way to stop spark jobs once the driver and executor pods are spawned? Would deleting the pods themselves be enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you will delete `executor` it will be recreated again and spark application will work. However if you will delete `driver` pod it will stop application.

> So killing driver pod is actually the way to stop the Spark
>   Application during the execution.

As you are new to `Spark` and you want to run it on Kubernetes, you should check [this](https://weidongzhou.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/running-spark-on-kubernetes/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

At present the only way to stop Spark job running on Kuberentes is to delete the Driver Pod (unless you have an app controlling Spark context which is able to manipulate it). Since all other job-related resources are linked to Spark Driver Pod with such as called `ownerReference`s, they will be removed automatically by Kubernetes.

Answer (score -1):

It should clean things up when the job completes automatically.

Comment: I was wondering how I would stop them while the spark job is running (not when they're already finished).

Comment: If you ctrl c the driver, it should also initiate a cleanup. You could also do it manually of course, but there’s a bunch of stuff it creates.