# spark-submit --kill vs deleting driver pod to stop a spark application on k8s. Are they same?

Tags: apache-spark

I am exploring options to gracefully kills a spark application running on k8s. I see from https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#spark-application-management that the **spark driver pod** on k8s represents the spark application and deleting that kills the app. Also it is recommended to use `spark-submit --kill` for killing the app.

I am in favor of using k8s DELETE APIs over spark-submit --kill CLI option. Does
spark-submit -kill does anything extra in addition to deleting the driver pod? Will there be any issues if I avoid using the CLI and delete the driver pod directly?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931049/18886549